# Parsing JSON Values into List<String>

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

Let me start by saying, I'm completely unfamiliar with json parsing. I have json that looks like this,

```
[  
   {  
      "locName":"Kansas"
   },
   {  
      "locName":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "locName":"Tokyo"
   },
   {  
      "locName":"Toronto"
   },
   {  
      "locName":"Des Moines"
   }
]
```

I just want to parse the names of the locations into a string list. How do I do it? 
my code looks like:

```
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
         if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&(parser.getText() == 'locName')) {
             myList.add(parser.getText());
             parser.nextToken();
          }
}
```

Comment: The `serialize`/`deserialize` methods of the [JSON Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) are generally all you will need and simpler to use than `JSONParser`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [json2apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com) to build a parser for you.

That said, here's the code you'd want to use:

```
public class Location {
    public String locName;
}
```

Later, when you want to parse your JSON:

```
List<Location> locations = (List<Location>)JSON.deserialize(myJsonString, List<Location>.class);
```

You'll get similar output from json2apex, but I just wrote this by hand.

If you want just the strings, you then just need to iterate:

```
String[] locationNames = new String[0];
for(Location item: locations) {
    locationNames.add(item.locName);
}
```

Comment: Man, sometimes I read a post, visualize the answer in my head, then you post it nearly verbatim. I guess that's a good sign. I almost posted this one from my phone since it's brief enough to get away with.

Comment: SFDC doc on [Json.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_class_System_Json) could be more useful. The example is pathetic (a scalar) and might not seem relevant to someone looking for a code sample resembling real world JSON input. It isn't until you read the [round trip JSON serialize-deserialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm) that you see an example with collections and even then, if you are only trying to deserialize, you might skip reading the example.

Comment: @cropredy Yeah, someone should file a complaint with the documentation team.